# Opening up the terminal on a Mac always starts a PHP process

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, php, homebrew

I am on a Mac running Yosemite 10.10.4 and every time I start terminal or open a new terminal tab I am inside of an actively running php process.  I must <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> before I can do anything else.  I don’t see any Mac terminal options that is automatically starting this process.

I have Homebrew installed and I’m using a LEMP stack, so I’m not sure if there is some misconfiguration there? I’ve searched everywhere, tried running `brew doctor` and `brew update`, but everything is ready to brew and up to date.

Here is my terminal output when starting a new session:

```
 Last login: Thu Aug 20 13:31:52 on ttys000
 ^C
 MacBook-Pro:~ adam2k$
```

And my php version:

```
 MacBook-Pro:~ adam2k$ php -v
 PHP 5.6.6 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2015 19:48:00) (DEBUG)
 Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
 MacBook-Pro:~ adam2k$
```

Comment: What does the general page of Terminal preferences show?

Comment: @Mark - it shows
    - On Startup Open: New Window with Profile: Pro
    - Shells Open with: Default login shell
    - New Windows Open with: Default Profile, Default Working Directory
    - New Tabs Open with: Same Profile, Same Working Directory

Comment: In System Preferences, select users and right click on its name. "Advanced options..." will appear. and that will show default shell - what is there? (You might need to enable editing)

Comment: pr equivalently from the command line ` dscl . -read /Users/username UserShell` making the obvious change

Comment: OK then what do the startup scripts ~/.bash_login ~/.profile etc show One of them probably start php

Comment: @Mark - thanks!  I'm seeing this in my .bash_profile: /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.6/bin/php  if I remove that will php not start when I restart my computer?  Is there a way to have php start and also not automatically open in terminal?

Comment: That is more complex you want it as an apache plugin - for dev look at camp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default shell that Terminal starts is found by running the command:

```
dscl . -read /Users/username UserShell
```

Making the obvious change.

The current Mac OS X default shell is `/bin/bash`. This runs various startup files including `~/.bash_profile`. Search these for PHP code and remove that line.

PHP can be started manually in a terminal but its main use is in a web server as an Apache (or other web server) plugin.